# ng-model value not binding outside filtered ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am new here and faced a problem with my code.

Unfortunately I  cannot use `ng-model` value in other parts of my code as `{{x.name}}`

```
<input ng-repeat="x in users | filter:{localip:lip} | filter:{publicip:pip}" 
       ng-model="x.name" value="{{x.name}}">
```

---

Dear Aleksey thanks. This work as you suggested.

Her is the code ;

```
        <input style="margin-right:20px;width:80px;float:right" 
               ng-repeat="x in filtered_users = (users | filter:{localip:lip} | filter:{publicip:pip})"
               value="{{x.name}}"> 
    </div> 
</nav> 
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="color:white">
         <span ng-bing="ip"> Genel Ip Adresiniz: {{pip}}</span><br> 
         <p>Yerel IP Adresiniz: {{lip}}</p>
    </div>
</nav>
<p ng-hide="!{{filtered_users[0].name}}">
    {{filtered_users[0].name}}
</p>
```

I am trying to hide this value if its null.

Comment: can you describe how `{{x.name}}` is used elsewhere? Or show the relevant code? Your current code is working, unless your filters are broken

Comment: Anywhere to use it as a value. This maybe <p>{{x.name}}</p>

Comment: may I use this value from ng-model.

Comment: it's actually bounded to an array `users`, where each element is used in `ng-model`. So technically you can have the same effect with `ng-model="users[$index].name"`. So if you want to use `ng-model`'s value, then simply use a known index and refer to an array: `{{users[0].name}}`. But I don't see why you would want to select each user manually by index, that's why I suggested `ng-repeat`

Comment: Dear Alexey, Thanks for your help. But as you see value is getting by a filter and I want to use this filtered value. So I should not refer to {{users[0].name}}.

Comment: then you can assign a new variable with a filtered result by modifying your `ng-repeat`. Try something like `x in filtered_users = (users | filter:{localip:lip} | filter:{publicip:pip})` (I don't remember the right syntax, but I think that's it). Then simply refer to {{filtered_users[0].name}} (or once again use `ng-repeat="x in filtered_users"` with `{{x.name}}`)

Comment: Dear Aleksey thanks. This work as you suggested.

Comment: Please post you controller code too, and be more descriptive as of where exactly are you facing the issue, and how you expect your output to be. This community will help you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not wise to use curly bracket `{{ }}` interpolation in AngularJS Expressions.

Instead simply use an expression in the `ng-hide` directive:

```
        <input style="margin-right:20px;width:80px;float:right" 
               ng-repeat="x in filtered_users = (users | filter:{localip:lip} | filter:{publicip:pip})"
               ng-model="x.name"  ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶"̶{̶{̶x̶.̶n̶a̶m̶e̶}̶}̶"̶ /> 
    </div> 
</nav> 
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="color:white">
         <span ng-bing="ip"> Genel Ip Adresiniz: {{pip}}</span><br> 
         <p>Yerel IP Adresiniz: {{lip}}</p>
    </div>
</nav>
̶<̶p̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶h̶i̶d̶e̶=̶"̶!̶{̶{̶f̶i̶l̶t̶e̶r̶e̶d̶_̶u̶s̶e̶r̶s̶[̶0̶]̶.̶n̶a̶m̶e̶}̶}̶"̶>̶
<p ng-hide="!filtered_users[0].name">
     {{filtered_users[0].name}}
</p>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice-).